# How to give read-only access for all schemas from db for user?

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to give read-only access for all schemas from DB for the already existing users?
and also access for future tables.

Answer (score 1):

Often you want to give a user read only permissions to all the tables in e.g. the atomic schema. (E.g. credentials for a BI / frontend on the data.) Granting permissions on individual tables, especially if you have lots of them in the schema, can be tedious.

A quick way is to execute the following query:

```
SELECT
'GRANT SELECT ON ' ||
schemaname ||
'.' ||
tablename ||
' TO {{ username }};'
FROM pg_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'atomic';
```

This generates the list of GRANT statements that can be copied and pasted at the psql command line to grant access to each individual table.

Comment: So, Redshift doesn't have a single command to give access for all schemas in the database?

Comment: It is but which i share above is perfect script.

Comment: I need to give access to future tables and schemas too. Your query only for existing tables only.

Comment: We only GRANT access to only existing tables.

Comment: Hi Aprit, Found something from this answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376623/how-to-grant-usage-on-all-schemas-in-redshift?rq=1

Comment: Try ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES